# How to use img tag physical way?

Tags: html, razor

For example, such a picture the way:

```
"C:/xxx.bmp"
```

I wrote:

```
<img src = "file: /// C:/xxx.bmp" />
```

But no picture ..
What should I do for it.

Comment: Is this going to be a local site or public? What is the document root set to? Why do you want to use an image like that?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a security vulnerability if the client could request local file system files and then use JavaScript to figure out what's in them.

The only way around this is to build an extension in a browser. Firefox extensions and IE extensions can access local resources. Chrome is much more restrictive.

Additionally, to access images from disk, you should use relative paths.

For example, if your directory structure is like this

```
C:/
     xxx.bmp
     index.html
```

And now in your index.html you can simply have `img` tag as

```
<img src = "xxx.bmp" />
```